How to perform state change of a Blazor component through its instance. Error - The render handle is not yet assigned
I am trying to alter a flag of a component through its instance but getting an error as The render handle is not yet assigned.
I have a component called PopMessage.razor
@if (isDisplay)
{
    <div>
       <span>Message</span>
    </div>
}

@code{
    private bool isDisplay = false;
    public void PopShow()
    {
        try
        {
            isDisplay = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
    }
}

Registered it as builder.Services.AddScoped<PopMessage>()
And in an another component Home.razor
@page "/"
@inject PopMessage _popMessage
<button @onclick="PopPrint">Pop message</button>
<PopMessage/>

@code{
    private void PopPrint()
    {
        _popMessage.PopShow();
    }
}

Now on click of the button it throws the exception message as The render handle is not yet assigned in the PopShow method.
I did not really understand the issue. The component <PopMessage/> is loaded. But on he call of the message PopShow throws this exception. Without StateHasChanged() it does not throw the exception but of course the state does not get updated.

I found this post, although if I want to do something like this how to do it. Because this kind of approach makes to very easy to show or hind a pop up message. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16646

The error means that Attach has not been called on the PopUpComponent instance and it doesn't have a RenderHandle.  This is provided by the Renderer when it attaches the component to the RenderTree.
What you are doing is registering the component as a DI service and then trying to use it in a page.  You can't do that.
See this question and answer for more details - System.InvalidOperationException: 'The render handle is not yet assigned.' in Blazor server
If you want to implement a parent to child relationship use simple binding, if more general use the notification pattern - see Best Way to Trigger Re-Rendering in Blazor Following Data Changes
